# Add zebra crossing to a project Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I've download the latest version of xcrossing from the trunk, I successfully added to my project and correctly create the dependency. If I build the library alone everything runs smooth, but if I try to build my project I get this error inside the Counted.h header

> "lexical or preprocessor issue 'iostream' file not found"

Looking for an answer I've found that the file that import a c++ header should have the .mm extension. The class that uses it is a .mm. I also made a search to check if there was another file using it, but not. 
I really do not know what to do.

Any guess that could help me? 
**UPDATE**
The headers that are creating a problem are ZXingWigdetController.h and QRCodeReader.h, if import them in header of the class that uses the qrcode I get the error :

> "lexical or preprocessor issue 'iostream' file not found"

If I import the ZXingWidgetController inside the header of the class that uses the qrcode and the QRCodeReader in the implementation file I get the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at CocoaPods website cocoapods.org.

I was trying to add ZXing to my project for ages.  In the end I used cocoapods and it worked with no problems.

Editing answer as per request...

The answer is just add the armv7s to the ZXingWidget project under Architectures and in the ZXingWidget library in Architectures.

Everyone should get CocoaPods though.  it really is an amazing tool.  All the frameworks I use go through it.

Comment: Thanks I will check it, and if it works I will set the mighty green flag.

Comment: No worries, it requires a bit of setup to install cocoapods (all explained on the website) but then all it takes is to add the name of the "pod" to a txt file.  Oh, you'd be best completely removing ZXing from your project before you start.  Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: CocoaPods seems a really great tools but it doesn't fix the issue, the project with all dependencies says that "ZXingWidgetController not found". I will try again at home. The fact that I don't understand is that the same project with xzing imported manually build fine on older version of Xcode. MAy I ask you if your project with zxing build fine on 4.5?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Xcode 4.5.  The thing with CocoaPods is that you'll need to remove everything that you did manually to begin with.  Then once you add the framework using CocoaPods you'll have a projectName.workspace file.  Open this in Xcode not your projectName.xcodeproj file.  Then to use the zxing in a file use #import <ZXing...> instead of #import "ZXing..."  Let me know what problems you are having if you can't sort it.  Oh, also remove all your stuff that you did to build settings to do with ZXing.

Comment: Found the fix but it doesn't deal with CocoaPods. Yes I removed everything in the project that deals with XZing. the answer is easier, post it for me so I could give you the answer, because even if Cocoapods didn't work this time it's an amazing tool and I'm really happy that you point it out.

Comment: The answer is just add the armv7s to the ZXingWidget project under Architectures and in the ZXingWidget library in Architectures